# Eclipse Package Explorer not matching physical folder structure

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Newbie question

I have downloaded a project from git repository using Eclipse (Import-> Clone URI).
It created a folder in my local MyDocuments git folder and I can also see the project in the Eclipse's Package Explorer.

For some reason, for any source file, say `HelloWorld.java` which I see inside the MyDocuments git project folder, I do not see `HelloWorld.java` in Eclipse's package explorer. I have changed perspective to `java/javaee/java` browsing etc.

Is there some setting/perspective in Eclipse where I can see all the source files?

Comment: Try importing as file structure, and to get a true answer screen shots will be needed.

Comment: Try the Navigator view.

Answer (score 0):

After successful cloning git repository inside eclipse, you need to import these project inside eclipse.

Click `Windows > Show view > Other` then select Git repositories view. Right click on `Working directory` then select Import project.

[image]